# How to log unicode character string with Poco::Logger?

Tags: c++, logging, poco-libraries

I'm using [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) C++ libraries version **1.7.5** for loading a few records from database and logging them in file with POCO logger utility. One of the string records is in unicode format which I saved in `std::wstring`. I can not find how to log `std::wstring` with POCO logger.

```
Poco::Logger logger;
std::wstring gameName;
...
logger.information("GameName: %s", gameName.c_str());
```

The result is:

```
2017-04-27 11:47:28.438 - GameName: [ERRFMT]
```

How to log `std::wstring` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poco does not support wstring logging directly and Poco's `format` functions use type safe formatting.

See [format](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.html#14526).

However Poco has a [UnicodeConverter](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.UnicodeConverter.html) class.

So you can convert the `std::wstring` to `std::string` via `Poco::UnicodeConverter::toUTF16` like:

```
std::string str;
Poco::UnicodeConverter::toUTF16(str, gameName);
logger.information("GameName: %s", str);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Assumming that `logger.information();` works as printf does, youu could try with `%ls`

for string:

```
logger.information("GameName: %ls", gameName);
```

for char:

```
logger.information("GameName: %lc", gameName);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it and the result is the same. I also tried `%S` which prints only `S`.